# Downvotes on question about Yahoo email, but no comments to improve

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked, [Yahoo Inbox Email Preview has text which is missing in Normal view](https://superuser.com/questions/1057881/yahoo-inbox-email-preview-has-text-which-is-missing-in-normal-view), which now has two downvotes.

But there is no advice or comments on what is wrong or how to improve it.

I have edited it couple of times, but still not sure if it is good enough. How can I improve this specific question?

Comment: You can't the question itself isn't on topic and likely the reason for the votes you have been receiving.  There isn't anything wrong with the question per say if it was on the correct website.  Many people, myself included, don't believe that questions that are not on topic are helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I improve this specific question?

From [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> it is not about …
>
> websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,

This includes questions about online email services like google, hotmail, yahoo, etc.

Questions about web services should be asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you for the response. (A) I will repost in webapps ; (B) But even on SuperUser, I saw (and used) the tags yahoo-mail & gmail & webmail ; If these topics are offtopic, why would there be such tags available ? (C) I see lots of similar questions about yahoo mail , and many have been upvoted with answers [[ http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail shows 44 other questions ]] (D) I am acurious to know why the original downvoters did not put in a comment about posting in webapps, but only they will be able to answer that !!

Comment: A lot of those are old questions.

Comment: Posted my question on webapps : http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91325/yahoo-inbox-email-preview-has-text-which-is-missing-in-normal-view